# API design: POST with query parameter for specifying relationship?

Tags: api-design

Say I have a User resource which must always be attached to another type of resource, a Business.

When creating a new User, is it OK to have the POST endpoint use a query parameter to specify the Business to use?

For example:

```
POST /users?business=123
{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"}
```

Comment: Why not POST /users { "user": {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"}, "business": 123 } ?

Comment: You haven't specified an API paradigm (e.g. REST) you're trying to follow, so yes, it's okay if it follows HTTP (which it does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can; there is nothing about HTTP that imposes a particular API structure. However, I would suggest you give the subject some thought.

API modelling is all about understanding your domain model; it depends on the relationship between `business` and `user` and the relative significance of these entities.

Here are my thoughts as to your main options; I cannot answer this question for you, but this will hopefully help you approach the problem in the right way.

**One-to-Many**

- A business may contain many users
- A user may only be linked to one business

If the users are treated as properties or components of a business, then make the users a child-object of the business.

```
POST /businesses/123/users
{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"}
```

If the users are viewed as distinct entities that are only linked to a business, then simply link the user to the business.

```
POST /users 
{ "user": {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"}, "business": 123 }
```

**Many-to-Many**

- A business may contain many users
- A user may be linked to many businesses

You could make the link to businesses a property of the user.

```
POST /users 
{ "user": {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"}, "businesses": [123, 789] }
```

Or, if the link to a business has substantial significance to your domain model, you could make a whole new entity that represents employment.

```
POST /users 
{ "user": {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"} } 

POST /employment
{ "user": 345, "business": 123, "commenced": "2016-09-01", "terminated": false }
```